# What data type can be used to support file uploads in Salesforce?

Tags: custom-object, attachment, files, fileupload, emailfileattachment

I have a custom object and I want to add a new field to support file attachments. For example, while creating new record, I want the user/admin to have an option to attach files to that record during creation. I also have an active process that will automatically sent email with the data to the user. I want to sent that attachment/file as well in the email.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to upload files using Apex code](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/131096/how-to-upload-files-using-apex-code)

Comment: i don't want to use apex. is there any way to do this with declarative tools?

Comment: A higher-level overview of options is available at https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/11333/can-users-upload-pdfs-word-documents-etc-into-salesforce-possibly-through-th

Comment: Just declarative tools? Check out the Files related list, which you would add to your object's page layout, allowing users to upload files and associate them to that record. https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=admin_files_related_list_setup.htm&type=5

Comment: This issue with Salesforce of not being able to add a simple file upload on a custom object is why I've been actively moving my org off SF, this functionality is basic by modern standards.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot attach a file to a custom object record at the time of creation of that record. There is no custom field type that accepts file uploads.

You will need to restructure your business flow to have the record be created, use out-of-the-box functionality (the Files related list) to attach a file, and then build automation that does *not* fire on record creation to construct and send your email, perhaps triggered by a status update of some kind on the parent record.